# The problem of connecting to the database from the application. The remote host forcibly terminated the existing connection

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, windows-server-2016

My application is on C# .net core 7 Winforms with Entity Framework 7.0. MS SQL server version 11.0.7507.2.

When connecting to the database, it gives an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HELko.png)

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then
> an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider,
> error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
> host.

The application runs on Windows Server 2016 - OS Build 14393.5006, and only on this OS is such an error, everything works on a regular win 11.
Also my other C# .Net Framework Winforms program without Entity Framework runs on Windows Server 2016.

I tried to set true and false in the db connection string for `trustservercertificate` and `encrypt` . Also tried without these parameters.

Comment: Can you add the connection string?

Comment: Potentially this isn't anything to do with Entity Framework but the difference between old `System.Data.SqlClient`s and modern `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`s. Does the server on which the SQL Server instance is installed have the necessary patches installed to [enable TLS 1.2 support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/tls-1-2-support-microsoft-sql-server)? (Both SQL Server itself and the host Windows operating system need changes.)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning
When I run the program on Windows 11, there is no error, so the problem is in Windows Server 2016 - OS Build 14393.5006. But judging by [link]( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/tls-1-2-support-microsoft-sql-server) article, then TLS 1.2 should be installed on it.

Comment: Use Wireshark to watch the TLS handshake to see if there is a cipher mismatch. Use IIS Crypto tool to check which ciphers are enabled and potentially enable missing ones.

Comment: Updated windows server to version 2019. Everything worked, but the essence has not yet been clarified. We will search.